# Java/JavaFX slider decimal points

Tags: java, javafx

I'm a new JavaFX programmer and my question is I'm getting multiple decimal points in the slider and I only want one.
I'm getting like 99.99999999999 for each value within but I would love to get only one like 99.9

The thing is printf is not applicable here I guess and I only know that way >.<

```
private void createView() {

        final GridPane radioGridPane = new GridPane();
        final Label frequencyLabel = new Label("something");
        final Slider sliderFrequency = new Slider(87.9, 107.9, 90);

        frequencyLabel.textProperty().bind(sliderFrequency.valueProperty().asString());
        radioGridPane.add(frequencyLabel, 2, 1);
        radioGridPane.add(sliderFrequency, 3, 1);

        this.setCenter(radioGridPane);
        radioGridPane.setGridLinesVisible(true);
    }
```

Comment: Look at the NumberFormat class.

Answer (score 4):

You were actually quite close. You can use [asString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/NumberExpressionBase.html#asString-java.lang.String-) method with the following signature:
`javafx.beans.binding.NumberExpressionBase#asString(java.lang.String)`
that accepts a format parameter.

Example usage:

```
public class FormatBindingSSCCE extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        final Label frequencyLabel = new Label();
        final Slider sliderFrequency = new Slider(87.9, 107.9, 90);
        frequencyLabel.textProperty().bind(sliderFrequency.valueProperty().asString("%.1f"));
        
        final GridPane radioGridPane = new GridPane();
        radioGridPane.add(frequencyLabel, 2, 1);
        radioGridPane.add(sliderFrequency, 3, 1);

        final Scene scene = new Scene(radioGridPane);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: You are a GOD <3
Much love and thanks dear genius programmer =D